# Como funciona exatamente o canvas.compose() do Lua?

Tags: lua

> **canvas:compose (x, y, canvas_src)**
>
> Faz a composição pixel a pixel entre dois canvas.
>
> O canvas passado como src`é desenhado sobre o canvas em uso (canvas)
> na posição passada.
>
> Recebe:
>
> - x: [number] Posição x da composição.
> - y: [number] Posição y da composição.
> - canvas_src: [canvas] Canvas a ser composto sobre canvas.
>
> Após a operação, o canvas de destino canvas possui o resultado da
> composição e o canvas src não sofre qualquer alteração.
>
> <sub>Fonte: [http://www.telemidia.puc-rio.br/~francisco/nclua/referencia/canvas.html#function_compose](http://www.telemidia.puc-rio.br/%7Efrancisco/nclua/referencia/canvas.html#function_compose)</sub>

**Exemplo:**

```
canvas -> 1920 x 1080
imagem -> 1280 x 720

canvas.compose(0, 0, imagem)
```

Como a imagem deve ser composta no canvas?

1. A imagem fica na posição 0,0 (esquerda/cima) com o tamanho original de 1280x720 e fica sobrando espaço embaixo e do lado direito.
2. A imagem começa na posição 0,0 (esquerda/cima) e é aumentada para preencher todo o tamanho do canvas (1920x1080).

Answer (score 0):

1. A imagem fica na posição 0,0 (esquerda/cima) com o tamanho original de 1280x720 e fica sobrando espaço embaixo e do lado direito.
2. O canvas não faz redimensionamento automático por padrão. Para redimensionar um canvas você pode tentar usar a função:  canvas:attrSize(height, width).